# Licencing C# Application

Tags: c#, licensing

I am wondering how I could set an expiration date of my application, but on a way that customers (customers actually doesn't exist, but let's say someday they will exist) need to paste a hashed key (my date) into their instance of the product.  For now I am solving it as described below, but I think this is not a good idea, let me explain:

I created small application with a datetime picker, and I am choosing a date until my application is active, for example 7.7.2016, and storing it as ticks into the registry and reading that ticks from the registry every time I start my application.   It's not bad, but the problem is that I must run the application on the customers pc to write to their registry by choosing a date and that's not good, because If I forget to delete my small application the customer could set the date as he wants. Another solution is to generate a date on my local computer, read a tick value from the registry copy and remotely enter key (ticks value from registry) or whatever to customer's pc.  But that is not good solution, and I am not happy with that, because customer might find out where I am storing ticks and copy it to another machine and another and another...

I was wondering if I could do the following:

On my developing machine I will run software for activation (key generator) and then I can choose a date until my software should be valid and get an id of the processor or of the hard drive and put it together to create a hash[ID+DATE] (so it is unique for every single machine) and store it to a database or registry, whatever, and on my application for customers I can next "unpack" the hash to get only the date part, so I can do following thing every time customer runs the application:

```
if(DateTime.Now > "HASHED date part")
    Message : application has expired!
```

Can I put together date+ID and hash it or protect it somehow so user can not read or modify it and I later cut date part and check if the application is still valid?

Answer (score 2):

Also, may I specifically suggest *(based on the experience of having sold a commercially successful product for, now, over 20 years ...),* that your license-control scheme should, above all, be **simple.**

I specifically(!) recommend that you should *not* attempt to check or to verify the CPU-id, nor any other physical characteristic of the licensed machine. Every tool that I have ever seen which purports to do this, proved to be unreliable. And furthermore, my customers have repeatedly told me that they appreciate the fact that the software *is* easy to move from one machine to another.

(Yes, we do scan a few directories just to make it less-than-trivial to "fiddle the date" ...)

We **trust** them, and guess what they do?  Uh huh ... they **buy** it.  If you're honest with someone and give them a product that really is worth what you charge for it, people are quite willing to be honest with you, too. *(And, don't lose sleep over the very few who are not... These people are not your **customers,** and they never will be. Never make life difficult for someone who **is** paying you money.)*

In the most recent version of our product, license information is stored in the Windows Registry, and it is inserted at product installation time using a DLL-file that is packaged with and called by the installer. It simply consists of a serial number, a product-features vector and an expiration date, in an obfuscated hexadecimal string.  The number is also used to conceal the "licensed-to" company name, which is displayed on the splash screen when the software starts.  Administrator privileges are required when the installer runs, for a variety of reasons including this one. To change the license information, you must reinstall.

Any software which you intend to sell to governments *(a very lucrative market segment),* generally **must** have license control features, and must not have a "free demo" option of any sort, because governments are usually not allowed to spend public money on anything that can be obtained (in any way) "for free."

One final comment: we do not provide any sort of "free demo." If you want to "try" our product, you must *buy* a time-limited copy.  You can apply the full price to a not-timed copy within the time-limit period.  Some people simply buy the *(less expensive)* time-limited license, use our product to fix their problem, and their problem *(as it happens)* never happens again, and they're happy and therefore so are we. A very significant portion of our revenue comes in this way.

To me, the point bears repeating: *"take care of your customers, and they will take care of you."* If your licensing scheme is "onerous and odiferous" ... **;-)** ... well, that's one of the things that people *do* very-seriously consider when deciding whether to buy your goods. You can lose a sale just because your scheme is a pain in the a*s.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.  The whole *point* of a hash is *specifically* that it is one way.  It's an algorithm that is *designed* to prevent you from being able to determine the original data that the hash was generated from.

You would need to *encrypt* the data if you want to be able to recreate the original data from the cipher data.

It's also worth noting that there are lots of ways of defeating your approach to prevent the user from running the program; licencing software well is hard.

Comment: Ahh, so I must/should _encrypt_ HARD DISK ID + DATETIME together and later _decrypt_ that crypt and cut date part?

Comment: @billy_56 *If* you encrypt the date then you could have the program decrypt it, to reconstruct what the date was.  Of course, there are plenty of ways for a user of that program to then manipulate that process, given that it's running on *their* machine, to ensure that they can run the program even after the given date.

Comment: Yes I understand, for now I just want to ensure single instance of application will work on only once computer. So I will try to do it as you said, encrypt - decrypt = read data and so on.. so could you give me advice which or what I should use to do that task? there is probably more ways to encrypt and decrypt something, so if we are talking about c# can you give me advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You could host a licensing server, and give each user a token to use for validation when they start your application. Then all your dateTime stuff could be handled on your server, and there'd be much less risk of your users being sneaky. It'd mean everyone running your app would need to be connected to the net though, which may be unacceptable to you.

Comment: Yes, its not acceptable because let's guess users will work offline

Comment: Exactly so.  It also requires "pinging the server," which means an active Internet connection.  Not a wise assumption to make.

Comment: Interesting, good points guys. Personally I'd be happy to assume everyone needs an internet connection but that's because most of my applications are dependent on one regardless.